# Constrained Optimization library for equality and inequality constraints

Tags: r, optimization, software

Any recommendations for choice of a constrained optimization library suitable for my optimization function? I am minimizing a i) non-linear function with linear equality and inequality constraints, and ii) have available the gradient and the hessian of the function.

If it helps, the function I am minimizing is the [Kullback-Liebler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence).

[constrOptim](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/constrOptim.html) only deals with inequality constraints. [Quadprog](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quadprog/index.html) handles quadratics. [Trust](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/trust/trust.pdf) does not support constraints. So the KL divergence does not fit into these solutions.

There are quite a few solutions on the [R Cran Task page for Optimization](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html). Iam able to perform the optimization in MATLAB using the [fmincon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/fmincon.html)() function which seems to use an interior-point or a trust-region-reflective. Ideally there is a library that is well-suited to the problem defined.

Comment: Are the constraints linear?

Comment: @cardinal - yes - the constraints are linear

Comment: So, if your equality constraints are $A x = b$, at least a *work-around* for `constrOptim` would be to include both $A x \leq b$ and $A x \geq b$. No?

Comment: That is very clever. I will explore this and see how it performs. You should consider posting this as an answer. I'll keep the question open for a couple days to see what other tools are available

Comment: @cardinal trick doesn't help for interior point method, like the one of constrOptim, since the method need a starting point into the interior of the feasible region -not on the border

Comment: Might be worth looking at [Ax platform](https://ax.dev/) (unaffiliated), at the very least might be useful for people that happen upon this question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both packages, alabama and Rsolnp, contain "[i]mplementations of the augmented lagrange multiplier method for general nonlinear optimization" --- as the optimization task view says --- and are quite reliable and robust. The can handle equality and inequality constraints defined as (nonlinear) functions again.

I have worked with both packages. Sometimes, constraints are a bit easier to formulate with Rsolnp, whereas alabama appears to be a bit faster at times.

There is also the package Rdonlp2 that relies on an external and in the optimization community well-known software library. Unfortunately, its license status is a bit uncertain at the moment.

Comment: Just want to add one property of Alabama inequality constraints which I found today. If your inequality constraints creates an infeasible region, then the code runs without any warning/error messages and takes the mean value of boundaries as fixed value of the parameter. For example if you have x > 6 and x <4, then the solution will provide a solution with x = 5 without any warning.

Comment: It seems this answer is still visited and read. Therefore, I would like to add that there is a new package *NlcOptim* (since 2015). It solves optimization problems with nonlinear objective and constraint functions, where nonlinear equality and inequality constraints are allowed. I do use it regularly.